# How to return a subdocument from a document based on parameters in Minimongo?

Tags: meteor, minimongo

**Short question**

Is there a way to filter documents client side?

**Long question**

So I have user accounts in a current Meteor JS project that store subdocuments, such as emails and comics.

```
_id: "jGZgBRqPRGFakcQRS",
comics:[
    {_id: "z4fq6QWKfQiX4G5gb",
    appearanceName: "Paradigm's Los",
    coverart: "sampleurl",
    heroName: "deadpool",
    publisher: "marvel"
    volNo: "-1"},
    {_id: "kvQLtT5nMdqhsxBRp",
    appearanceName: "Test",
    coverart: "sampleurl2",
    heroName: "deadpool",
    publisher: "marvel",
    volNo: "1"}],
emails: [{address: "email@email.com",
    verified: false}],
username: "test"
```

I also have a different collection named "Volumes", that passes the _id, appearanceName, coverArt, heroName, publisher, and volNo to the comics array on click. I currently have an {{#each}} displaying the documents from Volume. I want to display client side a certain link if a certain comic exists in the "comics" array AND if the _id of the item in the comics array matches the Volumes _id and a different link if it doesn't meet both requirements. Since aggregation doesn't work, I'm completely stuck. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find easy way how to filter data in subdocuments, so I always create separate collection. Then you need to join collections, you can read how to do it in this article: http://www.meteor.hromnik.com/blog/joins-in-meteorjs-and-mongodb

If you want to just find data in subdocument you can do it:

```
Meteor.users.findOne({
  'comics._id': yourComicsId
});
```

It will find user document with given comics id.